# How to contain a scrollable div element completely within another?

Tags: html, css

I want a scrollable (`overflow: auto`) `div` element to be completely contained within another `div`, i.e. it should only function as an overlay to the parent. However, I'm not able to make this work with padding within the child (which I want).

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknuds1/QYG5g/1/) for an example of my problem.

How can I accomplish what I'm after (if at all possible)?

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <p>Line 1</p>
        <p>Line 2</p>
        <p>Line 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
   border: 1px solid #666;
   height: 2.5em;
   padding: 0;
}

#child {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**

Note that for technical reasons left out of this scenario, I have decided to make the child element scrollable as opposed to the parent element: The child needs to cover the parent entirely, but that makes the parent display at least one scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. You were setting the height on the wrong element. I played with the borders just to make it easier to see what's going on.

http://jsfiddle.net/QYG5g/4/

Comment: Ah, good call! Your technique looks just about right. Thanks!